# React Fetch Post Returning 404

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using the default React template in Visual Studio 2022 to create a React application. In this app, I have a button with an on-click event to post data from the client to the web server via a Fetch Post.

My test case is here:

```
    async postChoresData() {
        const response = await fetch(
            'https://localhost:44400/Chores/PostData',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'React POST Request Example' })
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
    }
```

The endpoint I'm trying to call into is here:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ChoresController : ControllerBase
    {
    ...
        [HttpPost]
        public bool PostData(string data)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When the Fetch call is executed however, it returns a 404, saying the endpoint isn't found.
Why is it not found?

URL of site when running: https://localhost:44400/
Request URL (from network tab): https://localhost:44400/Chores/PostData

GET requests seem to work ok for me; for example, in React:

```
const response = await fetch('chores');
const data = await response.json();
```

And in the controller:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ChoresController : ControllerBase
    {
    ...
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Chore> Get()
        {
            return _choreRepository.LoadChores();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
When I run the app, I see this in the console:

```
https://localhost:7002
[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/weatherforecast', '/chores' ]  ->  https://localhost:7002
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://10.100.244.8/
```

If I try to post to https://10.100.244.8/, I get the following error message:
POST https://10.100.244.8/Chores/PostData net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

If I try to post to https://localhost:7002, I get the following error message:
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7002/Chores/PostData' from origin 'https://localhost:44400' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Home.js:17     POST https://localhost:7002/Chores/PostData net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Is your front-end served by the same server as the backend? If not, that would appear to be the cause of the problem. Your React app should be making requests to the .NET server on whatever port it's operating on

Comment: I've updated my post with more information. Basically, I've tried several different ports with different results based on how the proxy server is set up.